# How to use Font Awesome with Submit Type on the logout button

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, font-awesome

I need to make a post to log off, so I need an "input type".

How could I change this input so that I could use the FontAwasone class

I already tried to use the button tag, but it does not work inside the "a" tag.

```
           <div class="sidebar-footer">             

           <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                <span class="badge badge-pill badge-success notification">7</span>
            </a>

                <a>
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form" }))
                    {
                         @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                        <input type="submit" value="Logout" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    }    
                </a>
                //Need to use that Awesome  Class                   
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-power-off"></i>
                </a>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a button element should work in this case and let you put whatever HTML you desire inside.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
  <i class="fa fa-power-off"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: Thx for the help!